# Form Validator to check option and select check not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am having a issue with this script, I need the Form Validator as programed on the bottom to first check whether the radio with the select is targeted and then and only then request a time from that specific radios dropdown. It seem to be complete if i can get the:

```
if (document.getElementById('first').checked) {
    frmvalidator.addValidation("selects", "dontselect=000", "select a time");
}
```

statement work in javascript but as it only look for a time when its true but i seem to be missing something. Please assist

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" id="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
  <div>
    <div style="float:left; width:420px;";>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="first" value="SELECT" /> Attending a GROUP Intro      to Meditation ($15) on: <br/>
      <select name="selects"id="selects">
        <option value="000">Select a Date</option>
        <option value="2">April 23rd, TUES at 7:00PM - Group Intro to Meditation</option>
        <option value="3">April 27th, SAT at 11:00AM - Group Intro to Meditation</option>
        <option value="4">May 1st, WED at 7:00PM - Group Intro to Meditation</option>
        <option value="5">May 7th, TUES at 7:00PM - Group Intro to Meditation</option>
  </select>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio1" /> Scheduling a PRIVATE Intro to    Meditation ($200) <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio2" /> Scheduling an Individual Consultation ($300 / $475) <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio3" /> GIFT a Mentoring Session - 2 hr ($350) <br>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio4" /> Corporate Programs <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio5" /> Pro Bono Programs <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio6" /> General Inquiry <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio7" /> Receiving Information on Future      Intro Dates<br/>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left";>
      <label for='name'>Your Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
      <label for='email'>Email Address:&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
      <label for='confirm_email'>Confirm Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="confirm_email"> <br>
      <label for='email'>Contact #:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" name="contact"> <br>
      <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
      <textarea rows="8" cols="35" name="message";></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
<tr>
  <td>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      // Code for validating the form
      // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

      // for details
      var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
      frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
      frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
      frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 

      //frmvalidator.addValidation("selects","dontselect=000","select a time");
      var chktestValidator = new Validator("contactform"); 

      //chktestValidator.addValidation("radios","selectradio","Please select an option"); 
      chktestValidator.addValidation("radios","selone", "Please select a plan");

      if(document.getElementById('first').checked) {
        frmvalidator.addValidation("selects","dontselect=000","select a time");
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: It's better to post valid markup, some tags are missing and some are mis–matched. You are also using a form validation script that should be mentioned by name in the text of the question and in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you really want is a listener on the radio button with id "first" that, when checked, enables or disables the adjacent select element based on whether the button is checked or not. You can do that by:

```
<input type="radio" ... onclick="this.form.selects.disabled = !this.checked;">
```

You should disable the select element when the page loads by script, not in the HTML.

In the select element, you should set the first option to selected in the HTML:

```
  <option value="000" selected>Select a Date</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to need a blank space in front of id="selects"

Answer (score 0):

Your input radio must have an "ID" not just a name.. It works for me..

Comment: You should delete this answer if you're just going to post your other one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio1" />
```

To

```
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="radio1" id="radios" />
```

Maybe this can help..